# How to save remote repo credentials

Tags: magit

Linux Mint Emacs 25.1

Remote repo URL

```
origin (h t t p://git.remotehostname.git)
```

In application SmartGit when I pull/push data from remote repo, it's prompt credentials ONLY ONCE.

But when I try pull data by **Magit** - it's prompt credentials EVERY TIME when I use `magit-pull` or `magit-push`.

How I can save credentials in Magit?

Comment: What kind of remote do you have? Have you looked at https://github.com/magit/magit/wiki/Pushing-with-Magit-from-Windows?

Comment: origin (h t t p://git.remotehostname.git)

Comment: Does `git config --global credential.helper wincred` help? https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/

Comment: Linux Mint: Not help. I start "git config --global credential.helper wincred" in shell. But after try "magit-pull" it again ask me for credentials.

Comment: Uh, so you're not on Windows then? What about `git config --global credential.helper cache`? https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/#platform-linux

Comment: Not help. Same result.

Comment: Why is `http` spelled as `h t t p`? That might be the issue.

Comment: Sorry, must be http

Answer (score 1):

> How I can save credentials in Magit?

The best way to do that is to not do it and instead configure `git` itself. That way it works on the command-line and in Magit.

There are two problems with that approach:

- You have to learn how to configure this aspect of `git` and there are many different options available. On the other hand because many more people use `git` than Magit, it should be easier to search for relevant documentation and tutorials.
- Depending on how you configure `git`, these configurations may not carry over to Magit. Typically this happens when a user configures `git` in their shell startup file, but then start Emacs by clicking on a symbol. In that case `emacs` isn't a child process of, say, `bash` and so it does not inherit its environment variables.

Magit actually can remember your password for you and I just improved that functionality a few minutes ago (so make sure to update before trying this out). See the doc-string of `magit-process-password-auth-source`, it should have you covered.

Comment: How about if I am using [notabug](https://notabug.org)?... The help documentation for `magit-process-password-auth-source` only mentions `github`...